# GC signal from kernel instead of fixed JVM heap size

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, jvm

A fixed heap size is never going to be optimal. You either set it too low and run out of memory or set it too high and waste memory. The more JVM processes are running in parallel, the worse this problem gets. It is impossible to make use of all RAM in a machine even for one JVM. The closer you go to the maximum, the more you risk death by the OOM killer.

I understand the reason for a fixed heap size: garbage collection. Without knowing how much more memory is available, the JVM would not know when to perform GC.

An idea is to take this decision from the JVM to the kernel. Instead of suboptimal local decisions, the kernel could make optimal global decisions. I imagine this could work with the introduction of a new signal that tells the JVM to perform GC. The kernel would send this signal whenever it feels necessary to reclaim some memory.

Does anything like this exist? Do I misunderstand the problem? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: You misunderstand the problem. For the Oracle / OpenJDK at least, the kernel does not participate in GC. The heap is preallocated at JVM start, and is not touched by the kernel until program exit.

Comment: the heap isn't pre-allocated. only virtual address space is reserved, but not actually allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for a maximum heap size is to allow administrators to keep a runaway/leaky program in check; it's utterly unrelated to garbage collection. You can do the same with OS tools like `ulimit` but those tools don't integrate with Java, so Java code can't respond anymore if the limit is exceeded (because most OSs will kill processes forcefully when the limit is reached). So the inventors of Java needed a different way to do this: They allowed you to specify a maximum heap size on the command line and they gave you `OutOfMemoryException` which you can catch and handle without terminating.

Keep in mind that in 1994, when Java was published, 1GB of memory was still a lot. Also, most Java VM runs on mobile phones and embedded devices where 256MB of RAM is often the norm.

GC itself is usually triggered by how much free heap you have, no matter if there is an upper limit to the heap or not. Java always tries to regain memory before it asks the OS for more - GC can be expensive and more memory means more expensive. So it's a natural optimization to keep the number of current objects to a minimum to begin with. The reason why a lot of people think that the max. heap size will trigger a GC is this: When Java can't allocate any more memory from the OS because of the heap limit, GC will run very often. That's the time when most people realize that GC runs at all. So it's easy to mix that up when the two things aren't really connected.

Answer (score 0):

> A fixed heap size is never going to be optimal.

The heap size itself is never fixed. It grows and shrinks based on the needs of the application. Since Java 5, there is a feature that let's you return memory back to the OS if the collections do not use X% of space. It is tuned using the [XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap|outline) property.

> The kernel would send this signal whenever it feels necessary to
>   reclaim some memory.

How would the kernel know for example if java is hogging memory or if it can reclaim some of it from java ? Does the application really need 4GB of ram or is there a thread leak that is occupying more memory and leading to OOMs ? The kernel can never know that.

> Does anything like this exist?

The [XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap|outline) property is the closest I know that comes to giving memory back to the os.

More advice on setting the right values for these properties exists on the documentation I linked to.

> Unless you have problems with pauses, try granting as much memory as
>   possible to the virtual machine. The default size (64MB) is often too
>   small.
>
> Setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value increases predictability by
>   removing the most important sizing decision from the virtual machine.
>   On the other hand, the virtual machine can't compensate if you make a
>   poor choice.
>
> Be sure to increase the memory as you increase the number of
>   processors, since allocation can be parallelized.

Comment: Thanks! How does the JVM know if memory can be reclaimed? It doesn't, it just runs a GC and sees what happens. The kernel would do the same: send the signal and see what happens. And no program can ever know whether that 4GB is used for legitimate reasons or if it's a leak. Am I missing something?

Comment: As Deepak said: If the amount of free heap memory exceeds the MaxHeapFreeRatio, Java will return this memory to the OS.